# Pandas: fancy indexing a dataframe

Tags: numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe, df1, that is a year-long *5 minute* timeseries with columns A-Z.

```
df1.shape
(105121, 26)
df1.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2002-01-02 00:00:00, ..., 2003-01-02 00:00:00]
Length: 105121, Freq: 5T, Timezone: None
```

I have a second dataframe, df2, that is a year-long *daily* timeseries (over the same period) with matching columns.  The values of this second frame are Booleans.

```
df2.shape
(365, 26)
df2.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2002-01-02 00:00:00, ..., 2003-01-01 00:00:00]
Length: 365, Freq: D, Timezone: None
```

I want to use df2 as a fancy index to df1, i.e. "df1.ix[df2]" or somesuch, such that I get back a subset of df1's columns for each date -- i.e. those which df2 says are True on that date (with all timestamps thereon).  Thus the shape of the result should be (105121, width), where width is the number of distinct columns the Booleans imply (width<=26).

Currently, df1.ix[df2] only partially works.  Only the 00:00 values for each day are picked out, which makes sense in the light of df2's 'point-like' time series.

I next tried time spans as the df2 index:

```
df2.index
PeriodIndex: 365 entries, 2002-01-02 to 2003-01-01
```

This time, I get an error:

```
/home/wchapman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit)
    844             this = self.astype(object)
    845             target = target.astype(object)
--> 846             return this.get_indexer(target, method=method, limit=limit)
    847 
    848         if not self.is_unique:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_indexer'
```

My interim solution is to loop by date, but this seems inefficient.  Is Pandas capable of this kind of fancy indexing?  I don't see examples anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: You could resample `df2` to 5 min and fill it.

Comment: Thanks -- should have mentioned that I tried that too.  Got ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

```
t_index = df1.index
d_index = df2.index
mask = t_index.map(lambda t: t.date() in d_index)
df1[mask]
```

And slightly faster (but with the same idea) would be to use:

```
mask = pd.to_datetime([datetime.date(*t_tuple)
                           for t_tuple in zip(t_index.year,
                                              t_index.month,
                                              t_index.day)]).isin(d_index)
```

Comment: `.date` would probably be a useful method for DatetimeIndex (I think I'll put one together).

Comment: Thanks Andy, but my problem is a bit more complex.  I need to use the (boolean) _values_ of df2, not the index, as a fancy index to df1, as in the following (numpy):  

    a = np.arange(5)
    b = np.asarray([True. False, True, False, True])
    a[b]
    ---> arrray([0, 2, 4]).

As it happens, your code above pulls back the whole of df1, because the datetimes of df1 are all inside the days of df2.  What I need is for the correct _columns_ of df1 to be returned -- i.e. those identified by True values in the corresponding df2 columns.  And this selection will vary by day.